# Python Django ошибка Class 'Articles' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, python-3.7

как решить ошибку в Django `Class 'Articles' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)`

я пишу в VSCode

Comment: Ставьте плагин pylint-django

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343542/10898133

Answer (score 2):

1. В терминале установите pip install pylint-django
2. CTRL+SHIFT+P , вводием >perl и выбираем то, что на скрине выделено
3. Выбираем язык python
4. Попадаем в файл settings.json, вставляем 
   `{"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
   "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
   ],}`
5. Сохраняем файл
6. Конец

[image: 2)]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, только в строке 2 надо писать не perl, а pref.